# Make firefox remmeber password for children sites

Tags: firefox, passwords, password-management

You guy know that I have localhost for example, I installed many websites on the host, then when I login to a website, Firefox will ask to remember password, just click Yes and done.

However, It will remember that password for http://localhost only, meaning that later on when I login any child site of localhost, It will pre-fill the password that It remember last.

Is there any way to make it remember password for all the children sites (localhost/site-1, localhost/site-2)?
Please no extension or other software.

Comment: Your best bet is to edit your hosts file and give each site its own entry.

Comment: It will be hard because I have many things like localhost, and I think the way is hard for me to do.

Comment: Firefox (and all browsers) work out sites for passwords from their host name.  You have a single host name "localhost".  While you may consider these separate sites, browsers do not.  So you need to make them appear separate.  The easiest way is via the hosts file.